# SQL Transpose sum of field into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

Of all the SQL transpose questions using PIVOT and UNPIVOT I am yet to see one where you transpose a single row into columns. This is my query:

```
SELECT '' as Status, '' as "Count", sum(Created) as "Created", 
sum(Forwarded) as "Forwarded", sum(Replied) as "Replied"
FROM 
   (
      SELECT 
      CASE WHEN a.TO_WG_ID is null and a.CREATED_DATE_TIME =                          
         (select min(b.created_date_time) from ymtn.message b 
         where b.thread_id = a.thread_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS "Created",
       CASE WHEN a.TO_WG_ID is not null and a.FROM_WG_ID is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS "Forwarded",
       CASE WHEN a.TO_WG_ID is null and a.CREATED_DATE_TIME != (select 
         min(b.created_date_time) from ymtn.message b where b.thread_id =
         a.thread_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS "Replied"
       FROM ymtn.MESSAGE a left join YMTN.WORKGROUP b
       ON a.FROM_WG_ID=b.WORKGROUP_ID where b.WORKGROUP_ID='1STOP_PROCESS' 
) a
```

and this is my output from above query (with two static fields - Status and Count - which I may not need if I can just figure out to transpose it right):

```
Status    Count    Created    Forwarded    Replied
                     1693        209        1499
```

This is my desired output:

```
Status    Count
Created   1693
Forwarded  209
Replied   1499
```

Please help me find a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
 (  [Status] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Count] VARCHAR(10)
    ,Created INT
    ,Forwarded INT
    ,Replied INT
  )
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('', '', 1693 , 209 ,1499)
```

### Query

```
 ;WITH CTE
 AS
  (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT Created, Forwarded, Replied FROM @TABLE  --<-- Your Existing query here
    ) t
   UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (Created, Forwarded, Replied)) up
  )
SELECT N AS [Status] 
      ,Vals AS [Count]
 FROM CTE
```

### Result Set

```
╔═══════════╦═══════╗
║  Status   ║ Count ║
╠═══════════╬═══════╣
║ Created   ║  1693 ║
║ Forwarded ║   209 ║
║ Replied   ║  1499 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just union them.

```
Select 'Created' as Status, Sum... as Count
from...
union all
select 'Forwarded', Som...
union all
select 'Replied, sum...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to do the complicated transposing? I think you can use unions to give you what you want.

```
  SELECT
    "Created" AS Status,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM ymtn.MESSAGE a
  LEFT JOIN YMTN.WORKGROUP b
    ON a.FROM_WG_ID = b.WORKGROUP_ID
  WHERE b.WORKGROUP_ID = '1STOP_PROCESS'
  AND a.TO_WG_ID IS NULL
  AND a.CREATED_DATE_TIME = (SELECT
    MIN(c.created_date_time)
  FROM ymtn.message c
  WHERE c.thread_id = a.thread_id)
  UNION
  SELECT
    "Forwarded",
    COUNT(*)
  FROM ymtn.MESSAGE a
  LEFT JOIN YMTN.WORKGROUP b
    ON a.FROM_WG_ID = b.WORKGROUP_ID
  WHERE b.WORKGROUP_ID = '1STOP_PROCESS'
  AND a.TO_WG_ID IS NOT NULL
  AND a.FROM_WG_ID IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT
    "Replied",
    COUNT(*)
  FROM ymtn.MESSAGE a
  LEFT JOIN YMTN.WORKGROUP b
    ON a.FROM_WG_ID = b.WORKGROUP_ID
  WHERE b.WORKGROUP_ID = '1STOP_PROCESS'
  AND a.TO_WG_ID IS NULL
  AND a.CREATED_DATE_TIME != (SELECT
    MIN(c.created_date_time)
  FROM ymtn.message c
  WHERE c.thread_id = a.thread_id)
```

(Note: no sample tables & data were provided, so SQL is not test executed).